# Can Chromebooks print to USB printers?

Tags: usb, printing, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm posting this question because there is a lot of outdated information on the internet, from the days when Google Cloud Print was the only available option. For folks on WiFi, or printing to an off-site or at-home printer, this worked great. For mobile offices (i.e. in-vehicle printers) that was posing a problem as Bluetooth and USB were not supported.

Since StackExchange has such great SEO, I'm anticipating this post will out-rank the out-dated information that is currently dominant on the internet.

Comment: Because both Linux and Chromebooks use CUPS, ever since 'Native CUPS Support' was added in 2016, it seems to me that, these days, one _should_ be able to print to any printer that one can print to directly from Linux, directly from a Chromebook.  But while my printer mfg supports my printer under Linux, they won't help me with my Chromebook (which, of course runs on a Linux kernel...) and I haven't been able to figure it out on my own; I did attempt to install the CUPS drivers they provided for download, but couldn't.

Comment: ...Adding that info here as it may help others.  (I don't print often and so make do with saving to the cloud and printing from elsewhere. Its a Brother HL-L2300D Monochrome Laser printer that I have.) Also cool, related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/689584/cups-with-google-cloud-print.  I did just manage to print to it from a Chromebook via a Mac; perhaps I should add how here on SE or AskDifferent?  It was non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes! USB printing to HP printers (and others?) is supported.

The user is prompted to install the appropriate 'driver' app from HP. This seems to support LAN printing, but it also adds support for USB printing which is what I wanted. (since it's easier than setting up a WiFi hotspot)

Older printers such as the HP 895Cxi did not work, but apparently any late-model HP printer will work just fine.

Cannon does not yet have a print driver app for Chromebooks. Each printer mfg will add Chromebook support on their own schedule.